# GPS sports tracking app for Android WITHOUT social features

Tags: android, privacy, gps, sport, gps-tracking

This question might look a bit odd: I'm desperately trying to find a sports tracker app that **won't share** my activities with half of the world.

I know, that in most applications sharing can be switched off completely. Also, there are many apps out there that promise they share information only with my explicit permission.

However, I'd like to have a stronger guarantee than a correct privacy policy. If an app asks me to create an account or log in with an existing (Google+ or Facebook) one, I do not consider that app an option.

So, shortly: does such a GPS sports tracker app exist that writes GPS data *only and exclusively* into my phone's memory?

Of course, I'd happily pay the price, so that app doesn't need to be free.

(Interesting fact: for Blackberry, the [CascaRun](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/29342891) app does exactly that. It can share, but does not *require* you to log in or create an account.)

Comment: Had to delete my answer, appears you can no longer use Endomondo without syncing it with an account...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Sportstracklive( http://www.sportstracklive.com/ ).  I've just started using it.  I wanted something that would basically let me do what I do with my Garmin 305, but in situations where I would be away from a pc and the tracks woould be too long and exceed the Garmin memory.  For example a weeks backcountry ski trip.  My phone will store all that data, I can charge it through an adapter from AA batteries.

Then when I get back, I upload to the website, download gpx tracks to import to my pc (I use SportsTracks), then delete from the website.  In addition to the privacy options, there is no data to be shared.  It's a compromise I can live with.

Comment: Good app, this is what I looked for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

**OsmAnd** (Android) is a GPS app and famous as offline navigation app.

However, it has also the tracking features, so you load GPX track files, follow and track you activity, besides having some stats about the activity.

It is opensource and it has not 3rd party online trackers or SOCIAL sharing. You can download/install from Play and F-Droid

**OpenTracks** (Android)
Another opensource tracker  with time/elevation/distance stats.
To be able to display the tracks in a map you have to install **OSM Dashboard for OpenTracks**
Available at F-Droid

**Fito Track** (Android)
Another opensource tracker that can show display information such as date, time, duration, distance, speed and pace
Available at F-Droid

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OsmAnd

Answer (score 2):

There's [RunnerUp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.runnerup), which is not only privacy-minded, but also free and open-source. There's no data being sent anywhere (unless you want to connect an account) and you can check that in the code.

Right now, it may look aged and ugly, but make no mistake—it's quality and still being updated, just the UI hasn't been a priority.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Locus Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus.pro) which is perfect for running, hiking, cycling, etc.. It provides also navigation and vector maps (for free if you use *OpenAndroMaps*) and allows you to record waypoints and tracks and [export them in GPX format](http://docs.locusmap.eu/doku.php?id=manual:user_guide:tracks:export), offline.

It can even export your track into a picture file with the details of your activity (see the [documentation here](http://docs.locusmap.eu/doku.php?id=manual:user_guide:tracks:management&s[]=share&s[]=map#track_route_detail_screen) and scroll down to the *Track Overview* feature).

Answer (score 1):

Try [GeoCoach](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nukefuelled.geocoach). It can push data to online services if you want, but other than that your data is all stored on your device. You can also export data in various file formats if required.